# Can't configure a host with another host ip address

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I created an Ansible playbook to configure :
- a database server
- a nginx & php server

The database server needs to know the php server ip address to configure database access rights.
The webserver needs to know the database server ip address to configure the database access for the website.
I tried with delegate_facts :

```
vars:
    Database_server_name: "SVWEB-03"
    Web_server_name: "SVWEB-02"


- name: Web server ip address
  set_fact:
    Web_server_ip: "{{  ansible_default_ipv4.address  }}"
  delegate_to: "{{  Web_server_name  }}"
  delegate_facts: True
  when:
    - "Database_server_name in inventory_hostname"

- name: Database server ip address
  set_fact:
    Database_server_ip: "{{  ansible_default_ipv4.address  }}"
  delegate_to: "{{  Database_server_name  }}"
  delegate_facts: True
  when:
    - "Web_server_name in inventory_hostname"

- debug:
    msg: "{{  Web_server_ip  }}"
  when:
    - "Database_server_name in inventory_hostname"

- debug:
    msg: "{{  Database_server_ip  }}"
  when:
    - "Web_server_name in inventory_hostname"
```

But I have errors :

```
TASK [Web server ip address] ***************************************************************************************************
skipping: [SVWEB-02]
ok: [SVWEB-03 -> SVWEB-02]

TASK [Database server ip address] ************************************************************************************************
skipping: [SVWEB-03]
ok: [SVWEB-02 -> SVWEB-03]

TASK [debug] ***************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [SVWEB-02]
fatal: [SVWEB-03]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'Web_server_ip' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/home/murmure/ansible/playbooks/Install_Wordpress_Separate_DB_and_Web.yml': line 64, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - debug:\n      ^ here\n"}

TASK [debug] ***************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [SVWEB-02]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'Database_server_ip' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/home/murmure/ansible/playbooks/Install_Wordpress_Separate_DB_and_Web.yml': line 69, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - debug:\n      ^ here\n"}
```

Does someone have an idea about my mistake please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you need is in `hostvars`:

```
- name: Database server ip address
  set_fact:
    Database_server_ip: "{{  hostvars.Database_server_name.ansible_default_ipv4.address  }}"
```